# Telnetting switches from a different subnet

Tags: networking, interface, telnet

Hi so I built this network on packet tracer and managed to get everything working in terms of being able to for the hosts in different VLANS to ping each other however the last thing I need to do is telnet from the management laptop to each of the switches in the other subnet and I have been trying for the past hour or two to get it to work but I am not sure what else I can try doing so if anyone has any suggestions that will be great, I will put a picture up of the network for you to look at.

I have made sure that telnet is enabled for the switches and I have set the default gateway for each of the switches as the same address for sub interface that the router uses for the VLAN that the switches are in (VLAN 99)

[network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S6tL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Does Router0 have a route to the 192.168.5.0/24 subnet? Does the wireless router have routes to all the 172 networks?

BTW.... 172.168 isn't private address space! Its a very common mistake.  You should be using 172.16.0.0/12